# How to customize auto generate attribute in PhpStorm?

Tags: html, autocomplete, attributes, phpstorm

How can I auto generate some common attribute like `id` or `class` for specific tags (like `<p>` or `<div>`) in PhpStorm?

PhpStorm doing this for some necessary attribute (like `href` for `<a>`) but I want to customize it for myself.

Comment: What does this question has to do with programming?

Comment: How do you want this to work? Why just typing `<p id` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy You may ask questions about [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as long as they're clear and useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your custom [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.3/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) for this, like:

[image]

Typing `div` and hitting `Tab` will result in adding `<div id=""></div>` to your code.
Or, you can just use [Emmet abbreviations](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/): `#id` + `Tab` expands to `<div id="id"></div>`, `.cls` + `Tab`- to `<div class="cls"></div>`, `p#id` + `Tab`  to `<p id="id"></p>`, etc.